# How to fix msys64 error: Permission denied in C++

Tags: c++, gdb, clang, msys

I'm trying to run a simple C++ code in Visual Studio Code. I'm just setting up VS Code to work with C++ and i can't get it to run.

I'm getting this error:

C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\ld: cannot open output file C:/ALGORITMI/test.exe: Permission denied
clang++: error: unable to remove file: Permission denied
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1

I've tried unistalling MinGW and reinstalling it again, Also i tried this instalation with MSYS2 and nothing really works on VS Code.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void){

    int sz = 5;
    int *a;
    a = new int[sz];

    for(int i=0; i< sz; ++i){
        cout << "put in  "<< i+1 <<". member"<<endl;
        cin >>a[i];
    }

    for(int j=0; j< sz; ++j){
        cout << a[j] << endl;
    }


    cout<<"done..."<<endl;


    return 0;
}
```

I expected just a regular printing of the array members but i get the afformentioned error.

Comment: is the `test.exe executed somewhere else? or opened some kind of an editor?

Comment: Or is it still running somewhere.  The linker can not overwrite a running program.